# circuit to detect chess clock toggle change to fire BT button

Tags: signal, clock, detection

I was looking for simple circuit: (SamGibson's idea to add a 2nd reed switch proved possible, see update below.)

- to detect transition to flat 0 V when player B's clock is running.
- to detect transition to periodic 200 mV pulses when player A's clock is running.

When either detection occurs I want to 'fire' a blue tooth button click.

I am measuring at each end of the reed switch.

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

I am not really seeking whole project but seeking how to best/cheapest/easiest way to detect the change as shown and described. There is not a lot of space inside the clock for another magnet and reed switch and if the existing signal could be detected that would be cool/simple, no? The clock is driven by one AA battery so that is probably why the signal is on 1 V (I was thinking it was showing 200 mV pulses actually? Other solutions - this is an R&D effort - I just opened and measured the clock last night and found FLAT for B's clock running and 200 mV pulses when A's clock is running.

And the firing of the BT button I know how to do.

**Update 1-19-20**

I was able to squeeze and gluegun in place a 2nd reed switch on the A side using the same rocker magnet. 
Please see here -> [chess clock toggle showing detection by 2nd reed switch](https://youtu.be/a4qdTvbIask)
 
And there are some added images below.

Btw: The clocks original reed switch only has two leads.

I am next going to use this circuit to fire the BT button.
Please see here:
[double xor "chess clock - simple pulse generator from switch state change"](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%2015.472767971186109%2068%205%2050%0Av%20-256%20144%20-256%2080%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Aw%20-256%2080%20-256%2032%200%0Aw%20-160%2032%20-256%2032%200%0Aw%20-160%20112%20-64%20112%200%0Aw%20-160%20112%20-160%20160%200%0Aw%20-256%20144%20-256%20224%200%0Ag%20-256%20224%20-256%20240%200%0As%20-160%20160%20-160%20192%200%200%20false%0Aw%20-160%20192%20-160%20224%200%0Aw%20-256%20224%20-160%20224%200%0Ar%20-160%20160%20-96%20160%200%20100%0Ac%20-96%20160%20-96%20224%200%202e-8%200%0Aw%20-160%20224%20-96%20224%200%0Ar%20-160%2032%20-160%20112%200%200.001%0A154%20-64%2096%2048%2096%200%202%205%205%0Aw%20-160%2032%20-96%2032%200%0Aw%20-96%2032%20-96%2080%200%0Aw%20-96%2080%20-64%2080%200%0Ar%2048%2096%20128%2096%200%2050000%0Aw%20-96%20224%20128%20224%200%0Ac%20128%2096%20128%20224%200%202e-8%205.000000000000193%0Aw%20128%2096%20192%2096%200%0Aw%2048%2096%2048%2032%200%0Aw%20144%2032%20144%2064%200%0A154%20192%2080%20256%2080%200%202%200%205%0Aw%2048%2032%20144%2032%200%0Aw%20144%2064%20192%2064%200%0Aw%20256%2080%20288%2080%200%0A178%20288%2048%20336%2048%200%201%200.2%209.464922468955374e-11%200.05%201000000%200.02%2020%0Aw%20128%20224%20288%20224%200%0Aw%20288%2096%20288%20224%200%0Ao%2027%2064%200%204099%205%200.1%200%202%2027%203%0A38%2020%200%202e-8%203.0000000000000004e-7%20Capacitance%0A38%2011%200%201e-9%202e-8%20Capacitance%0A38%2018%200%2050000%20250000%20Resistance%0A)

[image]

[image]

Comment: what does this mean? ... `blue tooth button click`

Comment: Well, there are cheap blue tooth electronic buttons that will pair with smart phones and once paired can be used to remotely take a photo, as an example.  These are mechanical buttons that a human clicks - this mechanical click can be replaced with a relay etc. . . .

Comment: I've added into the question your new information, from comments on my now-deleted answer (so that the new information is available for other readers) since my answer didn't fit the updated space requirements. "*showing 200mv pulses*" That's not what's shown on [your left and middle scope images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLqpM.jpg) - approx 1 div peaks at 1V/div on left image (and a similar Vpp number on both of them). Only the right-side image of the three, at 10mV/div shows ~233 mV Vpp, but that is wrong - scope is not displaying the full waveform, as 10mV/div setting is too sensitive. HTH

Comment: @Kevin You have two clocks, one for white and one for black. The switch selects between them, turning on off and the other on. It's fair to assume that each clock is receiving identical pulses to advance it, with the reed relay deciding which. Are you saying that there are 30 ms spikes that pass through the switch when engaged in one direction, but which fail to get through when the switch is in the other position, and that this is the only thing used inside to determine which clock gets advanced?

Comment: This sounds "easy enough". I'm rushing out now. If no answer that suits within say two days pse advise me in a comment and I'll have a look.

Comment: Look at clock feed to any one clock - it will be active or off. A diode to a series resistor (maybe 100k) to a capacitor to ground loaded with a parallel say 1 M resistor MAY give you an OK signal. Later .

Comment: @SamGibson and Russell McMahon - please see update above - and thank you for your time and help! -Kevin

Comment: @Transistor and SamGibson with all of the re-edits and improvements you guys have done - why does the -2 down vote remain?  What value does this -2 serve?

Comment: The -2 will remain until the folks who gave them undo them or you receive enough votes to cancel them out.

Comment: Okay, to those that down voted now that SamGibson and Transistor have greatly improved this post - how about an undo on these down votes?  Or how about two up votes from those that have helped improve this post? 

And to what value do these -2 votes matter after the post has been improved?

Comment: You're shouting into a void. Nobody knows who downvoted as the system deliberately doesn't reveal it and it could be for any reason from bad question, badly written, they don't like your avatar or just being stupid. You'll have to live with it and try to do a good job on future posts. It would have been polite for them to leave a comment explaining why.

Comment: @Transistor you seem to think this is all good. I am not shouting. I am pointing out that as a first time ever poster here - there has been great help - but have lost credibility for trying. Simple solution. Abandon this user and try again, maybe, someday. The -2 two says this is not a good post. That's a shame, I think it is a very good post. And your effort and SamGibson's effort says you thought so too.

Comment: Don't worry about it. We've all had downvotes on questions and answers and often without comments. An upvote counts for +10 rep while a downvote counts for -2 so unless you are terrible your reputation will easily outpace the downvotes. "*... you seem to think this is all good.*" Not really. It's just the way it is.

Comment: @Kevin_Waite - I'm briefly online. Since I see that you have managed to use my approach of adding a 2nd (dedicated) reed switch, I've undeleted my earlier answer where I suggested that. *Transistor* has explained about downvotes - they are a vote about the state of a question/answer "at one time", but are not removed (nor is the voter notified) if the question is subsequently improved. Although I didn't like the initial approach of trying to use that signal from an unknown source, you've been kind enough to come back and confirm what worked to help others in future, so +1 from me. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Instead of trying to interface with existing electronics (with the risk you might affect its behaviour) one possible solution is to add your own extra reed switch controlled by the player A/B rocker mechanism (and add another magnet for your additional reed switch, if the mechanical layout needs one).

   That would be my initial approach (unless it was totally impractical, when more details are shown), as using a dedicated reed switch should allow you to avoid damaging to the existing electronics (and removes the need to reverse-engineer any of it).
2. It's unclear where you are connecting those orange & yellow cables inside the chess clock. The [signal you show when player "A" clock is running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLqpM.jpg) only reaches approximately 1V and so cannot be relied upon to be recognised as changing between logic states. And without knowing the design of the clock's electronics, we don't know what is driving that signal, to see if it could be modified (while still allowing the clock to work normally).
3. What other possible solutions did you consider (and presumably reject) so far, and why?
4. For the Bluetooth "button press" that you want to perform, I presume you have already got a solution for that.

Comment: Not really seeking whole project . . . seeking how to best/cheapest/easiest way to detect the change as shown and described....  There is not a lot of space inside the clock for another magnet and reed switch and if the existing single could be detected that would be cool/simple, no?  The clock is driven by 1 AA battery so that is probably why the signal is on 1V (I was thinking it was showing 200mv pulses actually?  Other solutions - this is an R&D effort - I just opened and measured the clock last night and found FLAT for B's clock running and 200mv pulses when A's clock is running.

Comment: And yes, the firing of the BT button I know how to do. Thank you Sam, Best -Kevin

Comment: @Kevin_Waite -  Hi, (a) "*if the existing single could be detected that would be cool/simple, no?*" Simple? No, because it means you having to interface with existing electronics, for which you don't have the schematic. I can *guess* an approach, but without reverse-engineering more of the clock, it's possible that this approach won't won't work (I'll add it to the answer). (b) It's still not clear what you mean by "*measured the clock*" i.e. where you are internally connecting the two wires visible in the photo. How did you decide to measure there? Is one of the two wires = battery 0V?

Comment: I am measuring at each end of the reed switch.

Comment: Incorporating your feedback @SamGibson, I think I am understanding a bit more. When the reed switch is open, A's clock runs because the pulses are not seen by the detection logic/circuit, and when the switch is closed, then the detection circuit sees the pulses and then runs B's clock. . . .  So it becomes a pulse detection question?  Easier?   And 'they' probably used pulses to use less power?  I think if I take dremel tool to the other toggle - B's toggle button side there is no magnet and not reed switch so I could target there? But it has to be robust, these clocks get whacked around..

Comment: @Kevin_Waite - "*When the reed switch is open, A's clock runs because the pulses are not seen by the detection logic/circuit*" You're guessing - that may not be true and is over-complicated (it isn't how I would design the clock). There is more reverse-engineering needed. I feared that might be the case, but I wanted to help give my preferred solution. Newly added information (too little space) means that I would want more analysis of the existing circuit, and I've got a busy couple of days ahead. I will add your new info into the question, so it doesn't get lost, and then delete this answer.

Comment: Answer undeleted, after the initial response that there wasn't enough room for a second reed switch, was changed and using a second reed switch was a solution.